Copy paste data from multiple sheets to one sheet using employee id as unique value
I have multiple excel sheets with employee ids as common value. I want to export range of data from multiple excel file to single excel file based on employee id.

Welcome to Superuser. Can you tell us the research you have done regarding this and what you have tried so far? Copying data from sheet to sheet is a pretty frequently asked question here, and there are several good answers that you should find and review before asking your own question.
